# Calculating total of multiple values from asp:CheckBoxList with Datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following asp.net code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cat_points_total" runat="server" DataSourceID="semester1" 
DataTextField="cats_points_total" DataValueField="cats_points_total" 
Visible="true"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="module_semester_1" runat="server" DataSourceID="semester1"
 DataTextField="module_name" DataValueField="cats_points"></asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:Label ID="sem_1_fb" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

<asp:Button ID="sem_1_cat" runat="server" Text="Test" OnClick="sem_1_cat_Click" />
```

A user can select multiple options from the checkboxlist. The `DataValueField` of `cats_points` is an int. In this case they all have a value of `20`. The `cats_points_total` found in the `DropDownList` control is another int value linking the max total a user can select from. In this case it's `120`.

I then have the following C#

```
protected void sem_1_cat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < module_semester_1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (module_semester_1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            string value = module_semester_1.Items[i].Value;

            int cattotal;
            cattotal = Convert.ToInt32(cat_points_total.SelectedValue);
            cattotal = int.Parse(cat_points_total.SelectedValue);

            int catselected;
            catselected = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            catselected = int.Parse(value);

            int catcalc;
            catcalc = cattotal - catselected;

            sem_1_fb.Visible = true;
            sem_1_fb.Text = "cattotal =" + cattotal + " catselected =" +
                            catselected + " catcalc =" + catcalc + ".";
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, no matter how many selections I make in the `CheckBoxList` I will get an output of `cattotal =120 catselected =20 catcalc =100.`

My expected result for selecting 2 values, each with a value of 20 to be;

```
cattotal =120 catselected =40 catcalc =100.
```

At this current time everything seems to work other than `catselected`, calculating the total of values from the CheckBoxList control. Any helped would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you parsing the values twice (i.e. with `Convert.ToInt32()` and `int.Parse()`)? Do it only one in way or another. Anyway, move your variables declarations out of the loop and add to the `catselected` using `+=`, otherwise you're overwriting the previous value with each new loop.

Try this:

```
protected void sem_1_cat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int catselected = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < module_semester_1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (module_semester_1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            string value = module_semester_1.Items[i].Value;
            catselected += int.Parse(value);
        }
    }
    int cattotal = int.Parse(cat_points_total.SelectedValue);
    int catcalc = cattotal - catselected;

    sem_1_fb.Visible = true;
    sem_1_fb.Text = "cattotal =" + cattotal + " catselected =" +
                    catselected + " catcalc =" + catcalc + ".";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried the above code however recieved a `Use of unassigned local variable 'catselected'` error? In regards to the parsing, I was just following along with a tutorial where they had done it.

Comment: cattotal does not change so it can be set outside of the loop as well. You could also set a boolean to determine if an item is selected so that you can move the sem_1_fb.Visible and sem_1_fb.Text out of the loop so that it is not set every time.

Comment: Hi mcclosa, just initialize the ints to zero. int catselected = 0;

Comment: @Drew you are right. I was focusing on the `catselected`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that did the job.

Comment: It's not important, but I'd replace the for loop with LINQ `int catselected = module_semester_1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected).Sum(li => int.Parse(li.Value));`